# How can I plot to multiple devices at the same time?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

When I am plotting, I often plot to an `eps` file and a `png` file like this:

```
postscript(file=paste(dir, output, "_ggplot.eps", sep=""), onefile=FALSE, horizontal=FALSE, width=4.8, height=4.0)
# Plotting code
dev.off()

png(paste(dir, output, "_ggplot.png", sep=""), width=450, height=300)
# Plotting code
dev.off()
```

The problem is that the plotting code is repeated twice. Is it possible to specify multiple devices for plotting?

Comment: `p <- qplot(1,1) ; l_ply(c("png", "pdf"), function(ext, ...) ggsave(paste("_ggplot.", ext, sep=""), p, ...))` could avoid duplication of code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can combine them using `dev.copy()`. For example,

```
  X11 ()
  plot (x,y)
  dev.copy (jpeg,filename="test.jpg");
  dev.off ();
```

Lookup `help(dev.copy)` for more details.

```
Usage:

     dev.copy(device, ..., which = dev.next())
     dev.print(device = postscript, ...)
     dev.copy2eps(...)
     dev.copy2pdf(..., out.type = "pdf")
     dev.control(displaylist = c("inhibit", "enable"))
```

Answer (score 7):

No it's not possible. At least not according to the manual for `?grDevices`:

> "Details: Only one device is the ‘active’ device: this is the device in
>   which all graphics operations occur. There is a "null device" which is
>   always open but is really a placeholder: any attempt to use it will
>   open a new device specified by getOption("device"))."

Answer (score 3):

Tyler is correct from the standard usage.  However, to make life easier, you can try an alternate method: wrap your plotting code as a function, so that you can then wrap a sequence of outputs.  That can at least simplify your code for producing output.

Another possibility that may work is to fork your process, via `foreach`, and each iteration produces a different type of output, depending on the index associated with the iteration.  I have done this to produce a lot of plots in parallel (though maybe I used Hadoop, I can't remember at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a for-loop:

```
devices <- c("pdf", "png")

for (i in seq_along(devices)) {

    if (devices[i] == "png") {
    ppi <- 600
    png(file = "Plots/regression.png",
        width = 8.4 * ppi, height = 6.5 * ppi, res = ppi,
        family = "Latin Modern Roman")
    }

    if (devices[i] == "pdf") {
        cairo_pdf(file = "Plots/regression.pdf", width = 8.4, height = 6.5,
                  family = "Latin Modern Roman")
    }

    # Insert plotting code

    graphics.off()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [R.devices](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.devices/index.html) package, you can do:

```
library('R.devices')
library('ggplot2')

devEval(c("eps", "png"), name="myfig", tags="ggplot", sep="_", aspectRatio=1.2, {
  gg <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl)
  print(gg)
})
```

This will generate 'myfig_ggplot.eps' and 'myfig_ggplot.png'.  The default `sep` is a comma and the default output directory is figures/.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot(....)+(...)
ggsave("file1.png")
ggsave("file1.pdf")
ggsave("file1.jpg")

ggplot(....)+(...)
ggsave("file2.png")
ggsave("file2.pdf")
ggsave("file2.jpg")