# Printing to multiple devices

Tags: r, device

I am trying to print to two devices simultaneously. I can for the most part create the outputs I want, but I am unsure how to change the `par$mfrow` settings for the first device.

```
pdf(file="test.all.pdf",width=7,height=10,pointsize=12,bg="white",paper="letter",pagecentre=T)
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

for(i in 1:12){
  temp <- rnorm(500,i,1)
  pdf(paste0("test_",i,".pdf"))
  dev.control(displaylist="enable")
  hist(temp)
  dev.copy(which=2)
  dev.off(which=3)
}

graphics.off()
```

I am trying to get individual .pdf files for each plot, then a combined .pdf file with 6 plots per page. Instead I am just getting a combined .pdf file with 1 plot per page.

I built the code I have based on this [post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7942612/1000343).

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7942612/1000343

Comment: Your goal (of having a 6-up format) should be accomplished by only using one call to `pdf`. It's the interior call to `pdf` (and `dev.off`) that is screwing things up.

Comment: @dayne I realized that but wanted to link the context for other users.  I'm going to delete my comment in a short while and suggest you do the same to avoid muddying the thread.  If you add the link in your post I'll delete the original comment.

Comment: @DWin I want it to output two files, so I need both calls to `pdf`. One file should contain all the plots, six per page. Then there should also be an individual file for each plot.

Comment: You are welcome to bang your head against the wall as much as you want but I do not think the graphics device model in R will support the nested calls. You could easily make a function that does two separate sets of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @DWin, I don't think this is possible as you've asked.  dev.copy() copies the device region, not a plot, which is why I think it cannot just place a plot in accordance with a different set of par() parameters.

It also seems to me much cleaner and easier to read and write to read to draw each plot twice I'm afraid.  If the code for drawing the plot is very complex, turn it into a function beforehand.

```
mycomplicatedPlot <- function(x, ...){
    hist(x,...)
    abline(v=mean(x))
    abline(v=quantile(x, probs=c(0.025, 0.975)), lty=2, col="red")
}

pdf(file="test.all.pdf",width=7,height=10,pointsize=12,bg="white",paper="letter",pagecentre=T)
    par(mfrow=c(3,2))

    for(i in 1:12){
      temp <- rnorm(500,i,1)
      pdf(paste0("test_",i,".pdf"))
          mycomplicatedPlot(temp, main=i)
      dev.off()
    mycomplicatedPlot(temp, main=i)
    }
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the code setup as you suggest, I was just trying to see if it was possible to do it another way in my pursuit to learn R.